# How do I prepare my preschooler for a move?

Tags: pre-schooler, moving

I am a parent of a 3 year old. We have a second child due at the end of April. In order to make room for then new baby we are moving at the end of this month.

How do I prepare my preschooler for the transition? We have already started talking to him about it and took him past the new house yesterday.

We have a few days between our close date and our move date so one of the things we are going to do is show him his new room and the rest of the house so he is more comfortable with the surroundings we are going to be living in.

What are some things to keep in mind when moving a preschooler for the first time and what kinds of things should we do to help him prepare better for an easy transition?

Comment: btw this is a 12 mile move and we don't know any neighbors so this is mostly about new house, new yard, not really much of an area adjustment...

Answer (score 2):

Your preschooler will probably have very little problem with the move in comparison with the adjustment to the new baby.  Be sure her room is the first you unpack so her bed and the like are set up for her on the first night. Take a tour of the house when you first arrive, talking about all the great things she will be doing in each room.
Make a REALLY big deal of her new bedroom, let her decorate (within reason) and really make it hers, this will help with the new house and the new baby!